# Joomla1.5 - Users search and profile view / edit at front end like admin

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I want users search, listing, edit features at front end same as in admin.

Exactly what I have to do is I will give admin access to a user through admin and when that user logs in front end he will see user manager menu at front-end and he will be able to search,view, edit any user profile.

How can I do this ? I am using joomla-1.5

Answer (score 0):

you can set user group to administrator so that user can access admin side,also he/she will be able to view /edit user details,but here you can not access admin side from front end.